# how do i generate a cordova app with sencha touch

Tags: cordova, cmd

Ok guys, I'm trying to create an app and I want to use senchatouch and cordova. Maybe I'm too tired or maybe I'm just stupid. But how do I generate a senchatouch-cordova-app?
I've downloaded all the stuff I need and now I'm sitting right in front of my cmd and I don't know what command I should type in.
The getting started guide didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/cordova

This tutorial is pretty straightforward. Just make sure you have every thing like Node, Phonegap and cordova installation on your end.